# OpenBSD and AB?

Tags: openbsd

What package is needed to install Apache Bench on OpenBSD 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ab utility can be found in the apache-httpd package. This will also install a non-base version of Apache, so be careful if you are using httpd.

From the apache-httpd pkg_add output:

> OpenBSD provides a custom Apache server, httpd(8), in the base system
>   which has been audited for security and may run in a chroot(2)
>   environment.  Users are STRONGLY encouraged to use the system httpd
>   rather than this port.